# Pagination in GridView counts all records when there are multiple models, but rows count expected in Yii2

Tags: php, gridview, pagination, yii2, dataprovider

I have problems with pagination when there are 2 models in GridView and in one row are inserted more than 1 record from second model.

DataProvider looks like:

```
    $query = Risks::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'pagination' => array('pageSize' => 5),
    ]);

    $query->joinWith(['solutions']);
```

Ins second model I have function:

```
  public function getSolutionValues (){

     ......
    $content ='';

    foreach ($order as $o){
        $model = Solutions::findOne($o);
        $content.= '<p>'.Html::encode($model->solution).'</p>';
    }
    return $content;

}
```

And in GridView I call this function:

```
            [
            'attribute' => 'solutions',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function ($model) {
                return $model->getSolutionValues();
            },
        ],
```

For example here are visible only first 3 records (instead of 5), because ir first row are inserted 3 entries from different model. (If one solution is inserted, then everithing is Ok)
[image]

And If I delete one solution from list, paginations doesn't change, I have to delete solution from DB and then only pagination doesn't count that entry.

Comment: Pagination does not depend on displayed content inside rows. Most likely there is something wrong with your query. Show how it's formed. Also I recommend use relations for such purposes http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#working-with-relational-data.

Comment: Actually all query is `$query = Risks::find(); $query->joinWith(['solutions']);` Only after `$this->load($params);` in search model there are more, but as I understand - that's only for searching. And you mean relations for pagination?

Comment: If with using relations was meant to get a list of solutions, then I have special order, I can't query all from top to bottom

Comment: Is correct pagination returned without `$query->joinWith(['solutions']);`?

Comment: Yes, then it is correct, but can't filter or sort becauce of Undefined table :(

Comment: Post `getSolutions()` relation code in this case.

Comment: `public function getSolutions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Solutions::className(), ['risk_id' => 'id']);
    }`

Answer (score 5):

Its quiet late but it may help someone else facing the same issue.

This is expected, and it happens when you are trying to paginate a JOIN query involving one-many relationship, because the JOIN query returns many rows for each primary record due to the one-many relationship. The solution is to specify select unique and selecting only those columns from the primary table.

In your case this should work:

```
$query = Risks::find()->distinct()->joinWith(['solutions']);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'pagination' => array('pageSize' => 5),
    ]);
```

Comment: `distinct()` makes all the difference. Thanks! This should be the accepted answer.